# I want to play a game

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords, video-games

I've been playing a lot of video games lately. After solving this crossword, you should know which video game I want to play next. Thanks to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) for test-solving and general feedback!

[image: cryptic crossword grid]

| Across | Down |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Hint linking incorrectly (7) | 1. I'm after gold fraud (8) |
| 5. Having Asgore lead inspires, but Undyne thinks leaders should be fish (7) | 2. Greek letter to king and prince promises accessible entrances (5) |
| 8. Mushroom Kingdom transportation ships to people working on gas mains (10) | 3. British territory is Adam's land? (4,2,3) |
| 9. Lynx, left out, after Jack and female monster (4) | 4. Piece almost there for archeologist of Pelican town (7) |
| 10. Flat, bony fish coming from ocean drop without hesitation (7) | 5. Deepnest princess warning alien (6) |
| 11. Spirit of wingless ship, previously leaderless (7) | 6. Angel hunting nun has knife at back (9) |
| 12. Some felon came raging, recorded (2,6) | 7. Messaged Theodore about former model (6) |
| 14. Judge after Charlie's case (5) | 13. Gray, family rival, is certain he prepared (9) |
| 17. Scattered notes identifying ailment from localized Mother (5)* | 15. Crazy hair trend provided by hardy knight (9) |
| 18. Firstly, them eating rarely ignites chatter against one's sauce (8) | 16. Company responsible for shooting fox in denial about plan (8) |
| 22. Umbrella Corporation founder bearing money for king (7) | 19. Vote; otherwise, back to synthesized music (7) |
| 23. Display former style making one independent (7) | 20. Leave Spain going north of peninsula (6) |
| 25. Raid runs dry (4) | 21. Actor essential to darn oldies (6) |
| 26. Working as tenant or resident of Sand Kingdom (10) | 24. Crosby exercises primarily to indulge (5) |
| 27. Villager currency is changing, mere lad (7) |  |
| 28. Moving within month (e.g. October) (2,3,2) |  |

*Originally:

> Recording device, with sound, from Mother; localization provided by scattered notes (5)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Hexomino has solved all of the cryptic crossword part in his earlier answer, but the continuation does rely on some of his work; clue explanations can be found there.

As to how you extract the actual answer from the puzzle; each of the shaded answers contains

> references to a video game (or series) in either the clue or the solution thereof.

Listing these in order below:

> A1: INKLING (solution, Splatoon)
>  A5: Asgore and Undyne (in the clue, Undertale)
>  A9: JYNX (solution, Pokémon)
>  A17: Mother localization (clue, Earthbound)
>  A22: Umbrella Corp./SPENCER (both, Resident Evil)
>  A26: Sand Kingdom/TOSTARENAN (both, Super Mario Odyssey)
>  A27: Villager currency + EMERALD (both, Minecraft)
>  D1: IMPOSTOR (solution, Among Us)
>  D4: Gunther/Pelican Town (both, Stardew Valley)
>  D5: Deepnest princess (clue, Hollow Knight)
>  D6: BAYONETTA (solution, Bayonetta)
>  D13: CATHERINE/Gray family rival (both, Red Dead Redemption)
>  D15: REINHARDT (solution, Overwatch)
>  D16: "shooting fox" (clue, Star Fox)

Taking the first letters of each gives the answer: the game you want to play next is

> Super Smash Bros.!

Comment: Ah, well done! +1

Comment: That answer fits incredibly well with rot13(gur pebff-senapuvfr angher bs gur pyhrf).

Answer (score 11):

**Partial Answer**

Completed crossword

> [image]

Clue Explanations

> **Across**
>  1. INKLING = (LINKING)*
>  5. HALIBUT = H(aving) A(sgore) L(ead) I(nspires), B(ut) U(ndyne) T(hinks)
>  8. PIPELINERS = PIPE (Mushroom Kingdom transportation) + LINERS (ships)
>  9. LYNX = J(ack) + (l)YNX
>  10. SEAMOTH = SEA + MOTH(-er) ("mother" = "drop" is a little dated but works, I think).
>  11. ESSENCE = (v)ESSE(l) + (o)NCE
>  12. ON CAMERA = (fel)ON CAME RA(ging)
>  14. CRATE = C(harlie) + RATE
>  17. STONE = (NOTES)* **referencing EarthBound, credit to Braegh for clearing this up in the comments**
>  18. TERIYAKI = T(hem) E(ating) R(arely) I(gnites) + YAK + I
>  22. SPENCER = PENCE in SR
>  23. EXHIBIT = EX + HI + BIT
>  25. ARID = (RAID)*
>  26. TOSTARENAN = (AS TENANT OR)*  (thanks to Braegh for the reminder)
>  27. EMERALD = (MERE LAD)*
>  28. ON THE GO = (m)ONTH EG O(ctober)
>
>  **Down**
>  1. IMPOSTOR = I'M + POST + OR
>  2. KAPPA = K(ing) A(nd) P(rince) P(romises) A(ccessible)
>  3. ISLE OF MAN = Adam being the first "man"
>  4. GUNTHER = GUN + THER(e)
>  5. HORNET = HORN + E.T.
>  6. BAYONETTA = BAYONET + (AT)<
>  7. TEXTED = TED about EX (former) + T (model, as in Model T)
>  13. CATHERINE = (CERTAIN HE)*
>  15. REINHARDT = (HAIR TREND)*
>  16. NINTENDO = NO (in denial) about INTEND (plan)
>  19. ELECTRO = ELECT + (OR)<
>  20. ESCAPE = ES + CAPE
>  21. ARNOLD = (d)ARN OLD(ies)
>  24. BINGE = BING + E(xercises)

Not yet sure how to use the shaded clues but working on it.

Here are the answers to the shaded clues

> **Across**
>  INKLING
>  HALIBUT
>  JYNX
>  STONE
>  SPENCER
>  TOSTARENAN
>  EMERALD
>
>  **Down**
>  IMPOSTOR
>  GUNTHER
>  HORNET
>  BAYONETTA
>  CATHERINE
>  REINHARDT
>  NINTENDO

Some ideas

> I'm not sure how to link the individual words but an idea I had was that you may want to extract certain letters from the shaded answers. For example, if we take letters which appear at the intersections of shaded answers we get IGHBYTERNE although I couldn't find a useful anagram here (BE THY REIGN is the most convincing thing I came up with). Perhaps doing something like this will work.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but 1D(i.e. with an "O") is also how the word is spelled in the recently-popular game Among Us. So possibly it has something to do with how certain words relate to other games?

Comment: @Sid thanks, I didn't know that (just thought it was an alternative spelling).

Comment: I think 17 is incorrect, and it should be rot13(FGBAR) instead. 26A's explanation is also not mentioned; should be (AS TENANT OR)*, right?

Comment: @Braegh Yes, you're right 26A is missing, sorry. Can you explain the reasoning behind 17 because I wasn't sure on that (I thought recording device bit would be the definition)

Comment: @hexomino 17A was probably my least favourite clue, due to how convoluted it was, but your answer made me realize it was also super ambiguous. In the spirit of fairness, I've updated the clue in the question, keeping the original in a spoiler tag for posterity. (Not sure how I didn't see the possibility for the updated clue until now.)

Comment: @hexomino: "recording device, with sound, from Mother localization" would be the definition, referring to an item from EarthBound (Mother localization, though technically Mother 2), the rot13(Fbhaq Fgbar). The new clue also fits; the same answer is an ailment from EB:Beginnings, which is the localization of the first game in the Mother series.

Comment: @Braegh Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I've cracked the rest according to a hunch I had. Working on the write-up; shouldn't be too long since you've already done pretty much all of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Sid You had the right idea, I should have followed your lead a bit more. Unfortunately, my knowledge in this area is not great.

Comment: @hexomino yeah. I did explore a bit on my own but my knowledge is limited as well. I did notice a few of the games but not enough of them to know what to do.